# Swift 2 Counter and reset

Tags: swift, counter

I am trying to create a very simple counter where the user taps a button and the text box displays in sequence 1 followed by 2 followed by 3 then resets to 1 and then counts again all using the same button.

My code so far:

```
class Counter: UIViewController {

    var count = 1

    @IBOutlet weak var sectors: UITextField!

    @IBAction func numberSectors(sender: UIButton) {

        if count < 3 {
            count+=1
            sectors.text = "\(count)"
        }
        else {
            sectors.text = "0"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@IBAction func numberSectors(sender: UIButton) {

    if count < 3 {
           count += 1
    } else { 
           count = 1
    }
    sectors.text = "\(count)"
}
```